# xmpp ruby client for google cloud messaging service

Tags: ruby, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to write a xmpp implementation in Ruby for GCM CCS.
My code

```
require 'xmpp4r'

sender_jid = Jabber::JID.new('my_app_id@gcm.googleapis.com')
client = Jabber::Client.new(sender_jid)
client.connect('gcm.googleapis.com', 5235)
client.auth('auth_token')
```

after client.connect .... I get this error :

```
fatal: No live threads left. Deadlock?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.use_ssl = true
```

solves this